# Quick question about integration of a piecewise defined function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bounds-of-integration, partial-functions

I have the following "quick" question about the piecewise function integration:

Say, I have to find $\int\limits_0^{1}f(x)d x$, with $f(x)$ being piecewisely defined on $\mathbb{R}$ as follows:
$$ f(x) = 
\left\{\begin{matrix}
\; 0&,&\text{ if } x\in (-\infty; 0] \cup (1; +\infty)\\ 
\; p(x)&,&\text{ if } x \in (0; 1]. \\
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

Then, my question is, what is the mathematically correct way to find the above interal?

Is it:
$$  \int\limits_0^{1}f(x)dx = \int\limits_0^{1}p(x)d x = P(x)\huge |_{\normalsize 0}^{\normalsize 1} \normalsize = P(1) - P(0) = \mathcal{P}_0.$$
Or is it:
$$\int\limits_0^{1}f(x)dx = \int\limits_0^{\bullet}0dx + \int\limits_{\bullet}^{1}p(x)dx = 0\huge|_{\normalsize 0}\normalsize + P(x)\huge |^{\normalsize 1}\normalsize = P(1) = \mathcal{P}_1.$$

I know, my question may seem a bit stupid, but yet, I'm still wondering which of the above options is correct.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Remember that the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (which you're invoking) has hypotheses that are necessary for it to be valid: the integrand must be continuous on the entire interval, and $P(x)$ must be an antiderivative on the entire interval. That definitely rules out the second option. The first option is correct, although if $p(0)\ne0$ then technically it is an improper integral and must be treated using a limit as the lower endpoint approaches $0$ from above.

Comment: This isn't a partial function, but a piecewise function. A partial function is one which may be undefined at some points in its "domain." This function, however, is defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @AJY, you’re right, just I was not that common to Calculus terms back when I was posting the question :)

Comment: One can prove that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two functions defined on an interval $[a,b]$, and $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ in the interval except for a single point $x_0$, then $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = \int_a^b g(x)\,dx$, in that both integrals exist and are equal, or neither of them exists. Taking that for granted, you can take $g(x)=p(x)$ on $[0,1]$, and conclude that $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = \int_0^1g(x)\,dx$.